# Launch and interact with MATLAB GUI from a C# Application

Tags: c#, matlab, user-interface, matlab-compiler, matlab-app-designer

I am familiar to C# and regularly code in it but MATLAB is totally a new application for me.

So, What I am trying to achieve here is design a simple GUI like a "Knob" in MATLAB and launch it through C# application.

Here's my MATLAB script for the knob:

```
function a = Modify_Figure_value(val)
fig = uifigure('Name','KnobValue','Position',[100 100 283 275]);

txt = uieditfield(fig,'text',...
'Position', [69 82 100 22]);

kb = uiknob(fig,...
'Position',[89 142 60 60],...
'ValueChangedFcn',@(kb,event) knobTurned(kb,txt),'Tag','knob');

set(fig.Children(1),'Value',val);
a = 1;
end
```

When I run the above script in MATLAB, the knob is displayed in a window.

Then I used the **MATLAB Compiler** to pack it as a **.NET assembly** named "**displayKnobValueIndotNet**" to be used in C# code (with class name as **Modify_Figure_valueclass**). So I wrote a WPF application which contains a button and when clicked upon should launch the knob:

```
public partial class Demo_function : UserControl
{
    displayKnobValueIndotNet.Modify_Figure_valueclass obj = 
    new displayKnobValueIndotNet.Modify_Figure_valueclass();


    public Demo_function()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       MWArray x = obj.Modify_Figure_value((MWNumericArray)25);   
    }
 }
```

But the GUI doesn't launch and there are no error or exceptions as well. Where am I going wrong?

And once I achieve the above I need to make the GUI interactive in the sense that when I change the value in the knob I get those values back in my WPF application. So, is this feasible?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to make some custom control from Matlab which you can integrate and use seemlesly into a WPF window(/form). Your Matlab "knob" will have to reside in a Matlab window(/figure). If it's just for the sake of a knob, there are plenty of example which can be found for "native" WPF knob.

Comment: The objective here is to load MATLAB GUI scripts from a C# application.

Comment: This might help: [Call MATLAB Function from C# Client](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html)